# Appending Geojson with json field using JQ

Tags: json, jq

I have a project I'm working on that creates a choropleth map with all US county borders loaded from `file1.json` and filled with a color gradient based on values in `file2.json`. In previous iterations, I just enter values manually into `file1.json`, but now I want to expand my map and make it more user-friendly.

`file1.json` is structured like this:

```json
{
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {
        "GEO_ID": "0500000US06001",
        "STATE": "06",
        "COUNTY": "001",
        "NAME": "Alameda",
        "LSAD": "County",
        "CENSUSAREA": 739.017
      },
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Polygon",
        "coordinates": [
          [
            [
              -122.30936,
              37.77615
            ],
            [
              -122.317215,
              37.778527
            ]
          ]
        ]
      }
    },
    ...
  ]
}
```

`file2.json` is structued like this:

```json
[
  {
    "County": "Alameda",
    "Count": 25
  },
  {
    "County": "Amador",
    "Count": 1
  },
  {
    "County": "Butte",
    "Count": 2
  },
  ...
]
```

I want to create a new file that includes everything from `file1.json`, but append it to include the relevent Count field based on the County field.

The result would look like this:

```json
[
{
  "type": "Feature",
  "properties": {
    "GEO_ID": "0500000US06001",
    "STATE": "06",
    "COUNTY": "001",
    "NAME": "Alameda",
    "Count": "25",
    "LSAD": "County",
    "CENSUSAREA": 739.017
  },
  "geometry": {
    "type": "Polygon",
    "coordinates": [
      [
        [
          -122.30936,
          37.77615
        ],
        [
          -122.317215,
          37.778527
        ]
      ]
    ]
  }
},
...
]
```

I'm new to using `jq`, but I've played around with it enough to get it running in PowerShell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a `test.jq` file which may help

```
# utility to create lookup table from array of objects
# k is the name to use as the key
# f is a function to compute the value
#
def obj(k;f): reduce .[] as $o ({}; .[$o[k]] = ($o | f));

# create map from county to count
  ( $file2 | obj("County";.Count) ) as $count

# add .properties.Count to each feature
| .features |= map( .properties.Count = $count[.properties.NAME] )
```

Example use assuming suitable `file1.json` and `file2.json`:

```
$ jq -M --argfile file2 file2.json -f test.jq file1.json
{
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {
        "GEO_ID": "0500000US06001",
        "STATE": "06",
        "COUNTY": "001",
        "NAME": "Alameda",
        "LSAD": "County",
        "CENSUSAREA": 739.017,
        "Count": 25
      },
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Polygon",
        "coordinates": [
          [
            [
              -122.30936,
              37.77615
            ],
            [
              -122.317215,
              37.778527
            ]
          ]
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jVLbjpswEH33V4zIPgQpRUCU0N0oDzRNq0pttmqShypClRfMLhvA1JhKaJNvT8cGdnOrVEug8cyZc@bi59@HHpRJVqVUMoiTlLnWc8lzsiEAL/gBGDNe5bI27sDwU5qxiBqDowD63RHe94OrGRmNuDhPcP6J/1BJyS74FZwEQEu40SWSHVZdySRNZA2SQyiYKj/lfFsVIOlDir0IngEVgtbAY@APzyyUJenBFpIS5BODHHtRyVXJFLNybVmNiFghKMRVHsqE51qAZ0WFCgr0h6YVIz0SMU3b305i8w4Ei6qQgbVpyuTQf9lP8HrDN9sggCn00beD2DQnBDXaijNaNIWGegKNFFrYcL/tFZOUSjejiaUNE0yt06CRkEYRWIXgBRMyYWWDUnyMhk8Qo1olGNmB1Zol7KZKvn8la9rybo5DC//bPACTHA5qaYasC6YW9qmhm/E0ZXpcenlGp4KQjV5ms@nLxHbXGHjTwnAHR//n@f2vLx9Vij2y1Vkv7bFtO6@ZiFmu/NVcQ8bH7tn9erH6qf2neNXM5YPWoa9LX4u18z5mmy@W66X/Y@5j3BveWrbjtdH9axePjGdMivq0h67p7zytH9sZtaGQcxElOb6Gt2E159g@vwG8c1zXGtq3w/HgLDL0LM8bO6MTdzD4DzbHc53RVbr3I9c75SPX7M7ak@4fkP1f)

I notice that "Count" is a string in your example output but it's a number in the sample file2.  If you need to convert that to a string you can include a call to `tostring`.  e.g.

```
.features |= map( .properties.Count = ( $count[.properties.NAME] | tostring ) )
```

or you could perform the conversion when the lookup table is created, e.g.

```
  ( $file2 | obj("County"; .Count | tostring ) ) as $count
```